# Maven in Intellij IDEA : Could not transfer metadata

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am building a maven project in Intellij IDEA. I meet the this problem:

Could not transfer metadata com.gam.eam.ci:eam-starter-java-app-without-db:231.100.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to gdd-snapshots (https://cmc.centralrepo.rnd.gam.com/artifactory/product_maven/): Transfer failed for https://cmc.centralrepo.rnd.gam.com/artifactory/product_maven/com/gam/eam/ci/eam-starter-java-app-without-db/231.100.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

I am sure the settings.xml and pom.xml are ok. Because the same code works well on my coworker's computer.

I try many ways, such as invalidating the caches and restarting the Intellij IDEA, restartint the machine, checking the proxy. All fail.

Can anyone help me? Any suggestions would be appriciated.

the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.gam.eam.ci</groupId>
    <artifactId>eam-starter-java-app-without-db</artifactId>
    <version>231.100.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

    <groupId>com.gam.eam.pair</groupId>
<artifactId>maos-indoormapservice-root</artifactId>
<name>IndoormapServiceRoot</name>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:http://code.gam.com/mAOS-TECH/IndoormapService.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

<modules>
    <module>model</module>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>deployment</module>
    <module>implements</module>
</modules>

<properties>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gam.eam.pair</groupId>
            <artifactId>maos-indoormapservice-model</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gam.eam.pair</groupId>
            <artifactId>maos-indoormapservice</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gam.eam.pair</groupId>
            <artifactId>maos-indoormapservice-deployment</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Try deleting the folder of the dependency in your `.m2` folder and do a reimport. It's probably in this path `.m2/com/gam/eam/ci/eam-starter-java-app-without-db`